# Semi group $S$, $x^2y=y=yx^2$ for all $x$, $y$ show that $S$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I can not understand few steps please just give me hint what actually done in second part .[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because
$$xyxyx^3y=x(yxyx^3y)=x(yxyxx^2y)=x(yx)^2x^2y=x(yx)^2x(xy).$$

Comment: I can not understand x^3 term in xyxyx^3y

Comment: Because of the identity $X^3=X$ valid for all $X\in S$

Comment: Thank you. I can understand now

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$
xyxyxy=xyxyx^3y
$
because of the identity $X^3=X$ valid for all $X\in S$. Now, we can bracket
$$xyxyxy=x(yx)(yx)x^2y=x(yx)^2x(xy)$$  OK ?

Answer (score 1):

In the step you pointed at, $x=x^3\,\forall x\in S$ is used repeatedly; then there's just a little rearranging using the associative property:   $xy=(xy)^3=(xy)(xy)(xy)=(xy)(xy)(x^3y)=x(yx)(yx)xxy=x(yx)^2x(xy)$.